# IMAP gmail - how to delete a mail forever on Mail.app Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, gmail, imap, apple-mail

I access gmail using IMAP on my Mac OS X.

When I delete a mail, it vanishes from Mail but if I quit Mail.app and start it again, the mail is there again.

It seems to be impossible to delete a mail from gmail using Mail.app IMAP.

Am I missing something?

Comment: after delete mail are you empty your trash?

Comment: yes I do and I also do ERASE DELETED MESSAGES... it appears to vanish. then I quit Mail and when I start it again, the message is there. The only way to delete something is from gmail page. This is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should setup your client as Google recommends, see here: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78892# (expand the "Apple Mail" section)

Comment: apparently the settings were corrupted. I deleted the plist, reload the mail, adjust the settings and it is now working. THANKSS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed all the settings they list [here](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/02/configure-gmail-imap-accounts-properly-in-apple-mail-and-on-the-iphone/)?